# When speaking of an archetypical kind of person, should plurals use "s" or " 's "?

Tags: writing-style, punctuation, grammar

What's the best way (for *reader* experience) to achieve the following? Let's say I am defining some kind of archetype, based on Eduardo Saverin (Facebook cofounder) ,and I call it an "Eduardo".

I want to repeatedly say:

- Eduardos do xxy.
- There are a lot of Eduardos in your company.
- You'll encounter Eduardos every day.
- Don't be an Eduardo.

"Eduardos" might be grammatically correct, but just is hard on the eyes.
Eduardo's seems a little better but I think is grammatically incorrect.

I don't want a work-around, not right now. I am interested in opinions or experience with this kind of writing issue. It seems to be worse if the name ends in a vowel or if the name is uncommon. So if I used "Karen", then "Karens do xyz" is less awkward.

Comment: Ugh right .. thanks .. I'll change this!

Comment: Apostrophes are for possesives.  If you use them for plurals, it makes you look like you shouldn't be writing.

Comment: The best reader experience is to properly use the punctuation.

Comment: I get your point, and intellectually, I agree ...  however ... from reader's perspective, experience ... "Eduardos" can be seen as a name (singular) ... 

so 
"you'll encounter Eduardos every day"  (I mean you'll encounter many Eduardos - but it can be read as - you'll encounter this guy Eduardos, every day)
then later
Often Eduardos hate it when you don't respond right away"
which, when read - seems grammatically incorrect (or awkward to the reader .. if they are reading Eduadros as a single person"

Comment: From a reader's point of view:  Don't monkey around with the apostrophes.  They have a specific meaning, and your proposal pokes holes in it and makes me have to stop and wonder just what you were thinking.  I have to ask myself "Is this another author who doesn't know the rules for apostrophes, or did this author actually mean something when misusing the punctuation?"#

Comment: "Eduardos" isn't a name, as far as I know.  It is the plural of "Eduardo."  "Eduardo's" means that something belongs to a particular Eduardo.  End of the discussion.

Comment: Your suggestion is "grammatically" incorrect and awkward to any English reader.

Comment: If the term isn't in widespread use, avoid it altogether. You can just about get away with "Don't be a Karen" but not this.

Comment: I seem to remember that Truss's answer, _italicise and then add apostrophe-s to form plurals of words used as words_, was upvoted last time.

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy of Lynn Miclea, Author

[image]

Comment: Excellent way to state the obvious!

Answer (score 1):

The reason it sounds odd is that your mind recognizes 'Eduardo' as a proper name, which it knows ought to be singular. If we switch to a class name that ends in a vowel — e.g. 'dingo' or 'alpaca' — the plural seems perfectly normal ('dingos', 'alpacas'). It is a little smoother with names that end in consonants, like 'Kens', 'Alberts', 'Sarahs'... You might be a little more comfortable using the 'potato' strategy: i.e., use 'Eduardoes' (adding an 'es', not an 's').

Comment: Thanks for the helpful analogy.Actually, I am writing about "Salieri" (the antagonist in the movie Amadeus) - as a archetype. Thus sometimes have to refer to him as a "person" (Salieri is jealous) ... and sometimes as an archetype (Salieris often are not malicious) .. and while grammatically correct, t seems awkward.

Comment: @CJCornell: Have you considered following the Latinate formula, using Salierii? Not sure if that helps...

Comment: oh .. gee .. i think that is a little too erudite for my audience (who gets confused at "Eduardos" : )

Comment: @CJCornell In an academic  paper, there is no reason for pluralize Salieri when you can use the singular to refer to the type: A Salieri is not often malicious. OR: The Salieri is not often malicious.

Comment: @Lambie: That's good, thanks.

Comment: No worries. I aim to please. At first, I couldn't understand what this whole thing was about then it hit me. Apples are good for you. Except a name is not an object....

Answer (score -3):

First of all, using a name to indicate an intentional stereotype often seems patronizing and unkind, and makes me suspect the validity of whatever the author has to say. It can work, but usually I think a different technique would be better
But when I see it along with repeated mused of the [greengrocer's apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Superfluous_apostrophes_(%22greengrocers%27_apostrophes%22)) I simply dismiss the author as ignorant and not worth my time, and put the book or essay down, and probably never again read anything by the author. Don't do it!